# conflicting while loops when logging sensor data from python to SQLite3 database

Tags: python, while-loop, sqlite

I have wrote a script that will measure the RPM, speed and distance travelled of a wheel using a hall effect sensor.  The script works fine and now i wish to write the values of `rpm`, `mps` (metres per second) and `Distance` to a SQLite database i have created called `halleffect.db`.

However when trying to do so I am having some issues as my original script to display the speed readings etc relies on a `while True` loop.

When i log the data to the database i want this to happen for an infinite time, until the script is ended by the user.  This issue I now have is conflicting `while True` loops and hence the logging stage is never actually reached.  If i take out the while loop inside the 'original' script then i have a edge detection error on the sensor.

Is there any possible way to have both of these while loops executing at the same time?  I am fairly new to python so possible making some rookie mistakes within my code.

**logHALL.py**

```
import time
import sqlite3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import math

dbname='halleffect.db'
Distance = 0.00
mps = 0
rpm = 0
elapse = 0
sensor = 5
pulse = 0
start_timer = time.time()
timer = 0
x=0

# get data from sensor
def getHALLdata():  
    def init_GPIO():                                        # initialize GPIO
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
            GPIO.setwarnings(False)
            GPIO.setup(sensor,GPIO.IN,GPIO.PUD_UP)

    def calculate_elapse(channel):                          # callback function
            global pulse,start_timer,elapse,zero_timer,x
            pulse+=1                                        # increase pulse by 1 whenever interrupt occurred
            elapse = time.time() - start_timer              # elapse for every 1 complete rotation made!
            start_timer = time.time()                       # let current time equals to start_timer
            zero_timer = time.time()
            x = zero_timer
            return x

    def calculate_speed(r_cm):
            global pulse,elapse,rpm,dist_m,Distance,mps

            if elapse !=0:                                  # to avoid DivisionByZero error
                    rpm = 1/elapse * 60
                    circ_cm = (2*math.pi)*r_cm              # calculate wheel circumference in CM
                    dist_m = circ_cm/100                    # convert cm to m
                    mps = dist_m / elapse                   # calculate M/sec      
                    Distance = (dist_m*pulse)               # measure distance traverse in meter
                    return mps


    def init_interrupt():
            GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor, GPIO.FALLING, callback = calculate_elapse, bouncetime = 20)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
            init_GPIO()
            init_interrupt()
            while True:     
                timer = time.time() - x
                if timer>1.5:                                # if elapsed time is greater than 1.5s assume wheel is at rest
                            calculate_speed(3.4)             # call this function with wheel radius as parameter
                            print('0rpm     0.00m/s     {0:.2f}m     Pulses:{1}'.format(Distance,pulse))
                            sleep(0.1)

                else:
                            calculate_speed(3.4)             # call this function with wheel radius as parameter
                            print('{0:.0f}rpm     {1:.2f}m/s     {2:.2f}m     Counter:{3}'.format(rpm,mps,Distance,pulse))
                            sleep(0.1)

    return rpm, mps, Distance

# log sensor data on database
def logData (rpm, mps, Distance):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    curs=conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("INSERT INTO halleffect_data values((?), (?), (?))", (rpm, mps, Distance))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print('DATA LOGGED!')

# main function
def main():
    while True:
        rpm, mps, Distance = getHALLdata()
        logData (rpm, mps, Distance)
        time.sleep(0.5)


# ------------ Execute program 
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to run two pieces of code simultaneously, you have two choices:

1. Run them as two separate programs in two different processes. If they need to share data, you must use IPC to communicate. This is called "multiprocessing".
2. Run them as two separate threads in the same program. This makes it easier, but still tricky, to share data in memory. This is called "multithreading".

The generic term to google here is "concurrency".